# Finding sum of all pixels in raster using QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster

I am trying to find the sum of all pixels in a raster, as shown below:

[image: My raster] [image]

How do I do this using QGIS?

Comment: We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Answer (score 10):

"Raster layer statistics" in the processing toolbox:

1. Select layer
2. Select band
3. See results

[image]

You can also save resulting stats into HTML file

Answer (score -1):

I do recommend you use R and RStudio to do this. You can install the package raster and do that in a really easy way. Just read the documentation about that.

Comment: The OP specified that QGIS was the targeted platform. If someone asks about R, then providing a *solution* using R would be appropriate, but giving an RTFM for a different platform isn't appropriate.